# React-native > Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource FAILED > Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs FAILED

Tags: android, node.js, react-native

When I try to run react-native run-android on my project, I keep getting these errors. I've try restarting my computer and clear editor history, but have yet to solve the problem.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> File 'com.android.builder.files.ZipCentralDirectory@30682eae' was deleted, but previous version not found in cache

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> File 'com.android.builder.files.ZipCentralDirectory@1579668f' was deleted, but previous version not found in cache